# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek' using textfsm module (regex)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-textfsm

I'm trying to use the `textfsm` module which uses regex, and importing data into a text file. Below is my code:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler      
from textfsm import *  

cisco_device = { 'device_type' : 'cisco_ios', 'ip' : 'x.x.x.x', 'username':'****0', 'password':'***9'}
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_device)

fo=("test.txt" , 'w')

output = net_connect.send_command("show ip int brief")

re_table = TextFSM('xr_show_int_br','r')     

data = re_table.ParseText(output)

print (output)
print(re_table.header)

for test in (re_table.header):
          fo.write(test)

fo.write("\n")

for row in data:
          for temp_row in data:
              fo.write(temp_row)
          fo.write("\n")


fo.close
```

But I'm getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gtomy200/Desktop/Py/test.py", line 11, in 
    re_table = TextFSM('xr_show_int_br','r')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/textfsm.py", line 549, in **init**
    template.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same error. Opening the file solved it for me.

```
with open('xr_show_int_br.txtfsm', 'r') as template:
    re_table = TextFSM(template)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like xr_show_int_br needs to be a file object.
You are getting the error [here](https://github.com/google/textfsm/blob/master/textfsm.py#L552)